# Please allow editing of the blurb that appears at the top of our Developer Story

Tags: bug, developer-story

How can I **edit** the ***personal statement*** text that appears at the top of my Developer Story in between my ***name*** and ***I want to work with*** line? I am referring to the text that appears in the yellow box in the screenshot below (which also includes **favorire editor**).

[image: Developer Story - preview]

I am able to edit other fields without any problem, but not this.

If not editable, how can I delete my Developer Story and start again?

Comment: Moderator: Please check my question again. It has been edited. It is not a duplicate of the question you indicated, or if it is, then the duplicate question does not specify that's it is referring to Developer Story', and also contains extraneous replies having to do with programming of field lengths, etc. This extraneous info dilutes the essence of the problem. Thank you.